# Replace key words in MS Word 10 using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm failing in replacing key words in MS Word 10 via Excel VBA. 
I can open the Word document from Excel and find the target key words but not replace them. It seems that I'm missing something.

My code is:

```
Sub ReplaceValues()
Dim wApp As Object
Dim wDoc As Object
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True
wApp.Activate

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\doc.docm", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

With wDoc
    .Application.Selection.Find.Clear.Formatting
    .Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text ="vGameName"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = "vTest"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Forward = True
    .Application.Selection.Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute Replace>=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

Carlos

Comment: Please describe exactly HOW it's "not working" ("failing"). If you don't describe the problem, we don't know what to look for. We can't duplicate your environment or the files you're working on, so it's pure guess work.

Comment: Its working now. Thanks Cindy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't referencing the correct sections to begin the replace:

```
With wDoc.ActiveDocument
    'Replaces in body, not in header/footer
    With .Content.Find
        .Execute FindText:="KeyWord", ReplaceWith:="Desire", Replace:=1
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using named Word constants, which are available with early binding (and require a reference to be set to the Word library), but your use of 'Dim wApp As Object' and 'Dim wDoc As Object' implies the use of late binding. Try:

```
Sub ReplaceValues()
Dim wApp As Object, wDoc As Object, strFnd As String, strRep As String
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
strFnd = "vGameName": strRep = "vTest"
With wApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wDoc = .Documents.Add("C:\doc.docm")
  With wDoc
    .Range.Find.Execute strFnd, , , , , , True, 1, , strRep, 2
  End With
End With
End Sub
```